# File.Delete deleting both the original and converted file

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, file-io, asp.net-web-api

This is my API method which uploads the .caf file to the server, converts into .mp3 and deletes the .caf file. But the problem is that both the original file and the converted file are being deleted instead of only the original file.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ActionName("UploadCompetitionEntry")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadCompetitionEntry([FromUri]string folderName)
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType));
        }

        string path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/" + folderName);

        MultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(path);
        var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        // Log exceptions
        await task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted)
            {
                // Log t.Exception
            }
        });           

            var bodyPart2 = provider.FileData.Where(p => p.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.Replace("\"", string.Empty) == folderName).FirstOrDefault();

            if (bodyPart2 != null)
            {
                string savedFile2 = bodyPart2.LocalFileName;
                string originalFile2 = bodyPart2.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
                string uniqueFilename = string.Format(@"{0}", Guid.NewGuid());
                string newFile2 = uniqueFilename + Path.GetExtension(originalFile2);

                // Copy file and rename with new file name and correct extension
                FileInfo file2 = new FileInfo(savedFile2);
                file2.CopyTo(Path.Combine(path, newFile2), true);
                file2.Delete();


                if (folderName == "music")
                {
                    //converting .caf to .mp3 and creating a new .mp3 file
                    MediaFuncs.ConvertToMp3(Path.Combine(path, newFile2), uniqueFilename);

                    //deleting the .caf file
                    FileInfo file3 = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(path, newFile2));
                    file3.Delete();
                }
            }         


        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new ResponseMessage<Object> { success = true, message = "Media Uploaded" });

    }
```

And this is my converter method

```
 public static void ConvertToMp3(string filename, string uniqueFilename)
    {
        string musicPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/" + "music");

        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

        info.FileName = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/" + "ffmpeg.exe");
        info.Arguments = " -i " + filename + " " + Path.Combine(musicPath, uniqueFilename + ".mp3");

        System.Diagnostics.Process p1 = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info);
    }
```

Am i doing something wrong? If anyone knows any other way to delete just the original file, please please let me know, i have been banging my head about it all day  :(

EDIT: I put a breakpoint and checked. I think am deleting the .caf file before the conversion is complete. Because when i put the breakpoint just after calling the converter method and before deleting the file, the .mp3 wasnt deleted.

So now how do i stall the deleting till the conversion is complete?

Comment: You have 2 `Delete()` methods there. Did you try debugging and checking which one of them actually deletes which file?

Comment: Additionally, are you _certain_ an `.mp3` file has been generated in the first place?

Comment: The audio file is first stored without any extension and has a weird name, so am copying the file and adding the extension and deleting the old no-extension file. It works great till here... i checked, the old file is deleted. But after that when there are both the converted and original file in the folder, and am trying to delete the original file, it deletes both of them.

Comment: @Oded Yaa when am removing the code for deleting the original file, both the .caf and .mp3 files are created in the folder

Comment: @Oded and Blachshma Hey i wrote some latest findings in EDIT, please check it and let me know if u have any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the conversion to finish before deleting the source file.

To do that, you can simply call:

```
p1.WaitForExit();
```

At the end of `ConvertToMp3`.

See [`WaitForExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) on MSDN.